# Subcomplex of the standard $n$-simplex having nonzero $H_{n-1}$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, cw-complexes, simplicial-complex

This is an additional exercise of Hatcher's Algebraic Topology book (link: [https://pi.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/AT-exercises.pdf](https://pi.math.cornell.edu/%7Ehatcher/AT/AT-exercises.pdf), section 2.1).

Let $X$ be the standard $n$-simplex with its natural $\Delta$-complex structure and $A$ a subcomplex with $H_{n-1}$ nonzero. How can we show that $A=\partial X$? Using the simplical chain complex of $A$, we see that $A$ must be $(n-1)$-dimensional. There are exactly $n$ $(n-1)$-simplices in $X$. How can we show that $A$ must contain these all? It will suffice to show that if $A$ is the union of $<(n-1)$ faces of $X$ then $H_{n-1}(A)=0$. Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the boundary map from degree $n$ to degree $n-1$, and use the fact that $H_{n-1}(X)=0$.

Comment: The boundary map from degree $n$ to degree $n-1$ is trivial of course, because $A$ must be $(n-1)$-dimensional, i.e. it has no $n$-cells.

Comment: Yes, but look at the boundary in $X$. Cycles in $A$ of degree $n-1$ are boundaries in $X$.

Comment: A cycle in $A$ is also a cycle in $X$. Since $X$ has $H_{n-1}=0$, such a cycle should be a  boundary in $X$. But every boundary in $X$ is of the form $k(\sigma_0+\cdots+\sigma_n$, where $\sigma_0,\dots,\sigma_n$ are the $(n-1)$-dimensional faces of $X$. This implies that $k=0$ and that there are no nontrivial cycles in $A$, right?

Comment: @user302934 You got it.